# Finite trees with forests realizing all partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-groups, partitions, trees

Removing interiors of some edges in a tree with $n$ vertices leaves a spanning-forest
with $k$ connected components (given by subtrees) having respectively $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$
vertices. We get thus a partition of $n=\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_k$.

Is there an easy characterization of all trees with $n\in \mathbb N$
vertices realizing as above all $p(n)$ different partitions of $n$ (where $p(n)$ defined by
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n) q^n=\prod_{j=1}^\infty (1-q^j)^{-1}$ counts the number of partitions of $n$)?

*Examples*: All Dynkin diagrams $A_n$ work, Dynkin diagrams of type $D_n$ work
for odd $n$ but do not realize the partition $2+2+\ldots+2$ for even $n$.
$E_6$ does not work ($3+3$ is impossible), but adding an additional neighbour to one
of the two vertices of degree $2$ leads to graph $\Gamma$ on $7$ vertices which works.
Removing an arbitrary leave from $\Gamma$ leads however always to a graph
(on six vertices) which does not work.
$E_7$ and $E_8$ both work. For tripods with three legs of length $1,a,b$ there are obstructions
related to divisors of $2+a+b$. (It is easy to show that all partitions containing two inequal parts are realizable by a tripod with a leg of length $1$. For partitions with all parts equal there is no choice for an associated spanning-forest
leading to fairly simple necessary conditions.)

(Remark: The problem makes sense for simple finite graphs but trees seem already
quite messy.)

*Motivation*: We can consider edges $\{i,j\}$ of simple graphs with vertices $\{1,\ldots,n\}$
as transpositions $(i,j)$ of the the symmetric group $\mathcal S_n$.
Simple graphs correspond thus to subsets of transpositions in $\mathcal S_n$
and can be considered as generating sets of subgroups with a structure of
Cayley graphs.

Edge-transpositions of a simple graph $\Gamma$ (with vertices $\{1,\ldots,n\}$)
generate the full group $\mathcal S_n$ if and
only if $\Gamma$ is connected and finite trees correspond thus to minimal generating
sets consisting only of transpositions.

Composing in any order all $n-1$ different edge-transpositions of a tree with $n$ vertices
yields always an $n$-cycle.

A permutation with cycle-lengths $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_l$
is thus always the product of at least $\sum_i (c_i-1)$ edge-transpositions.

A tree with $n$ vertices realizing all partitions of $n$ corresponds thus to a minimal generating set of $\mathcal S_n$
consisting of transpositions such that all conjugacy-classes of $\mathcal S_n$
have representants realized in an optimal way.

There is also a fun-motivation: Procrastinating by proving things (finding a counterexample or realizing all partitions) for a given tree is somewhat enjoyable (and perhaps instructive for students). Finding complicated trees (realizing all partitions) is probably challenging.

*Variations*: On can also ask for trees realizing only a subset of partitions (for example
into distinct parts, into odd parts, corresponding to a conjugacy class of given signature etc.) There is perhaps no longer a good motivation for doing this (except if the resulting classification turns out to be interesting.)

Comment: Generating and testing all trees gives counts which correspond to [A277687](https://oeis.org/A277687) for all terms listed in OEIS, suggesting that the characterisation is that "the chromatic symmetric function in the p basis has a nonzero coefficient for each possible term" (whatever that means - I need to do some more reading).

Comment: Very interesting! The next step is to check wether the trees contributing to A277687 have exactly the partition-property. Hopefully this is the case if the two problems are related.

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, my earlier observation follows trivially from theorem 2.5 of Stanley, [A symmetric function generalization of the chromatic polynomial of a graph](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/100.pdf), Advances in Math. 111 (1995), 166-194.

Comment: @Peter Taylor. Thanks for this useful information.